# jni.h and expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’

Tags: c, macos, syntax, java-native-interface, header-files

My working environment is mac OSX 10.8.3.

now I'm testing JNI.

I made HelloJNI.java file and execute javac and javah command in terminal.

So I got HelloJNI.java, HelloJNI.class, org_owls_jni_HelloJNI.h files.

then I put

```
gcc -g -l/usr/local/java/include -l/usr/local/java/include/linux -shared HelloJNI.c -o libhello.so
```

command to run program. And faced with 2 error messages.

1. jni.h: No such file or directory
2. expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘void’

I've searched internet and found a solution which says upgrade my jdk to 1.7. But I can not do that because other people uses 1.6. So I need another solution to handle this problem with jdk 1.6.

For second problem, I found some article in stackoverflow. they say they were missing some syntax. But for me, I can not find any problems before void. please, take a look my header file.

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class org_owls_jni_HelloJNI */

#ifndef _Included_org_owls_jni_HelloJNI
#define _Included_org_owls_jni_HelloJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     org_owls_jni_HelloJNI
 * Method:    printMessage
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_owls_jni_HelloJNI_printMessage
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

I think here's no problem, because it was automatically generate by command javah.

I thank you very much for your advises in advanced.

Comment: Have you seen `jni.h: No such file or directory`? You do not have the file of `jni.h` in your /usr/include of /usr/local/include, it is necessary for your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first error is because you don't have a `jni.h`, it's that simple. You have to find out where it is and ensure it's on your include path.

And, by the way, that's done in `gcc` with `-I` (upper case eye), not `-l` (lower case ell). The latter is for specifying *libraries* to use rather than directories to add to the include path. That is, I believe, your specific problem here.

The second error is caused by the first, it's because you have this unknown token before `void` in:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_owls_jni_HelloJNI_printMessage
```

no doubt because of the missing `jni.h`.

Comment: Yeah, it seems you are right. I've replaced lower letter el with capital letter i. and error code has changed. as soon as I check first one(jni.h matter). I'll choose your answer. Thanks a lot for your kind teaching.