# jni in linux(Cent6): Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: linker, java-native-interface, centos

I'm now working with JNI.

I did things below:

1. I made HelloJNI.java. It simply link library libhello.so.

   ```
   static {
     System.loadLibrary("hello");
   }
   ```

like this. of course I have body also, but nothing special.

1. then I made class file, C file and header file.
   I commanded

   ```
   #javac HelloJNI.java
   #javah -classpath /usr/guest/workspace/path/ -jni package.HelloJNI
   no errors till now.
   ```
2. I made libhello.so.

   ```
   # gcc -shared -fpic -o libhello.so -I/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/include -I/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/include/linux HelloJNI.c
   ```
3. When I run this project in eclipse, error appears like below.

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hello in java.library.path
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
       at org.owls.jni.HelloJNI.<clinit>(HelloJNI.java:7)
   ```

I've tried this one, but does not work.

```
    # chcon -t texrel_shlib_t libhello.so
```

Thanks for reading and your wise solutions:D

- somebody talk about PATH thing. but I can not understand where to put that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by myself.

its cause was javah command.

i did like below.

```
javah -classpath /home/guest/workspace/.../src org.owls.HelloJNI.
```

and the method in generated header file is different with what I expected.

I expect something like

```
JNIEXPORT JNICALL void Java_HelloJNI_say(JNIEnv* env, jobject j){}
```

but below is actually generated.

```
JNIEXPORT JNICALL void Java_org_owls_HelloJNI_say(JNIEnv* env, jobject j){}
```

this is the main reason of my problem.

eventhough I threw out myself, but many thanks for someone who shares my problem.

have a good day :D

Answer (score 0):

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/library/"`. You can do this either from your command line or add it in your bashrc
Good links to read  http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html  and [jni.h and expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208513/jni-h-and-expected-asm-or-attribute-before-void)